# How to declare a variable that stores an object returned by reference?

Tags: c++, reference, return, return-type

C++ references are still confusing to me. Suppose I have a function/method which creates an object of type `Foo` and returns it by reference. (I assume that if I want to return the object, it cannot be a local variable allocated on the stack, so I must allocate it on the heap with `new`):

```
Foo& makeFoo() {
    ...
    Foo* f = new Foo;
    ...
    return *f;
}
```

When I want to store the object created in a local variable of another function, should the type be `Foo`

```
void useFoo() {

    Foo f = makeFoo();
    f.doSomething();
}
```

or `Foo&`?

```
void useFoo() {

    Foo& f = makeFoo();
    f.doSomething();
}
```

Since both is correct syntax: Is there a significant difference between the two variants?

Comment: `(I assume that if I want to return the object, it cannot be a local variable allocated on the stack, so I must allocate it on the heap with new)` This is taking a problem, and making it worse. Simply do not return the variable by reference: return it by value and let the optimiser (or C++11 move semantics) do their job.

Comment: Actually the `Foo& f = makeFoo();` version probably won't compile.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit why not?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Ref to temporary?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit is it a temporary though?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: What temporary?

Comment: Oh, hey, it works when the expression is already a reference to a non-temporary. Duh. Okay.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit "Let C++11 move semantics do their job" Can you point to some resource explaining how C++11 move semantics is relevant here?

Comment: @cls: Any resource that correctly explains move semenatics should enlighten you to its relevance here(try wikipedia: "move semantics"). The whole point is reducing the cost of unnecessary copies. Just make sure your Foo objects are designed to take advantage of it. Mainly, you want to ensure that the object's "largeness" is not in the object itself, but referenced externally.  A prime example is `std::vector`, which internally is just a few pointers.  But those pointers can reference huge amounts of data.  The vector can be moved by simply copying and nullifying the pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first code does a lot of work:

```
void useFoo() {
    Foo f = makeFoo();  // line 2
    f.doSomething();
}
```

Thinking of line 2, some interesting things happen. First, the compiler will emit code to construct a `Foo` object at `f` using the default constructor of the class. Then, it will call `makeFoo()`, which also creates a new `Foo` object and returns a reference to that object. The compiler will also have to emit code that copies the temporary return value of `makeFoo()` into the object at `f`, and then it will destroy the temporary object. Once line 2 is done, `f.doSomething()` is called. But just before `useFoo()` returns, we destroy the object at `f`, as well, since it is going out of scope.

Your second code example is much more efficient, but it's actually probably wrong:

```
void useFoo() {
    Foo& f = makeFoo();   // line 2
    f.doSomething();
}
```

Thinking of line 2 in that example, we realize that we don't create an object for `f` since it is just a reference. The `makeFoo()` function returns an object that it has newly allocated, and we keep a reference to it. We call `doSomething()` through that reference. But when the `useFoo()` function returns, we don't ever destroy the new object that `makeFoo()` created for us and it leaks.

There's a few different ways to fix this. You could just use the reference mechanism you have in your first code fragment, if you don't mind the extra constructors, creation, copying and destruction. (If you have trivial constructors and destructors, and not much (or none) state to copy, then it doesn't matter much.) You could just return a pointer, which has the strong implication that the caller is responsible for managing the life cycle of the referenced object.

If you return a pointer, you've *implied* that the caller must manage the life cycle of the object, but you haven't enforced it. Someone, someday, somewhere will get it wrong. So you might consider making a wrapper class that manages the reference and provides accessors to encapsulate the management of the objects. (You could even bake that into the `Foo` class itself, if you wanted to.) A wrapper class of this type is called a "smart pointer" in its generic form. If you're using the STL, you'll find a smart pointer implementation in [the  `std::unique_ptr` template class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee410601.aspx).

Comment: I agree mostly, but you could give a hint so smart pointers in the last paragraph. This would reduce copying costs and also free the object as soon as the smart pointer goes out of scope.

Comment: True, Skalli. I sharpened it up a bit for that.

Comment: Actually, the description of the first `useFoo` is wrong. The compiler will **not** emit code to default-construct `f`. It will just set aside enough memory to copy-construct `f` with the result from `makeFoo`.

Comment: @Bart van Ingen Schenau, is that guaranteed by the standard, or implementation-defined? Or is it dependent on which constructors and operators `class foo` implements?

Comment: @MikeB: It is guaranteed by the standard that the default constructor won't be used in `useFoo`. The details when memory gets set aside are up to the implementation.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the first one will make a copy of the returned reference, while the second will be a reference to the return of `makeFoo`.

Note that using the first version will result in a memory leak (most likely), unless you do some dark magic inside the copy constructor.

Well, the second will result in a leak as well unless you call `delete &f;`.

**Bottom line: don't**. Just follow the crowd and return by value. Or a smart pointer.

Comment: So I should leave everything as is, just change the return type of `makeFoo` to `Foo` instead of `Foo&`?

Comment: @cls: You allocate Foo on the stack and return a copy! So no `new` involved.

Comment: @Skalli What if Foo is a large object and I do not have the memory or time to copy it?

Comment: @cls the compiler will probably optimize it away. If you're really concerned, return a `std::shared_ptr<Foo>`.

Comment: @cls: Luchian Grigore was faster and he's right: Use a smart pointer. There are several distinct smart pointers you can use each with a focus on a special use-case. std::shared_ptr<Foo> should be the most fitting for your use-case.

Comment: Are smart pointers suitable for parallel programming with OpenMP?

Answer (score 2):

A function should never return a reference to a new object that gets created. When you are making a new value, you should return a value or a pointer. Returning a value is almost always preferred, since almost any compiler will use RVO/NRVO to get rid of the extra copy.

Returning a value:

```
Foo makeFoo(){
    Foo f;
    // do something
    return f;
}

// Using it
Foo f = makeFoo();
```

Returning a pointer:

```
Foo* makeFoo(){
    std::unique_ptr<Foo> p(new Foo());  // use a smart pointer for exception-safety
    // do something
    return p.release();
}

// Using it
Foo* foo1 = makeFoo();                 // Can do this
std::unique_ptr<Foo> foo2(makeFoo());   // This is better
```

Comment: For your second example, why not just return a `unique_ptr` and leave the decision of throwing away the safety to the caller?

Comment: I prefer to leave the decision of how to use it to the caller. Returning a raw pointer lets them put it into any kind of smart pointer they want. You're also less likely to run into ABI issues if the function and the caller aren't compiled against exactly the same version of the standard library.

Comment: Returning `unique_ptr` also allows them to put it into any kind of smart pointer they want(they can call release just as you did in the function), and it's self documenting.  When a function returns a raw pointer, I can't make any assumption about what actions need to be taken to ensure that it is managed properly.  It may be dynamically allocated with new, or malloc, or it may not need to be managed at all.  As for your second point, I can only say I've never personally run into any such issues, but I won't make an argument from incredulity.