# Creating objects in a loop

Tags: c++, pointers, for-loop

Here is a method creating a `Clustering` object and returning it by value.

```
Clustering ClusteringGenerator::makeOneClustering(Graph& G) {
    int64_t n = G.numberOfNodes();
    Clustering zeta(n);
    cluster one = zeta.addCluster();
    for (node v = G.firstNode(); v <= n; ++v) {
        zeta.addToCluster(one, v);
    }
    return zeta;
}
```

This loop calls the method multiple times and adds the pointer to the return value to a vector.

```
    int z = 3
    for (int i = 0; i < z; ++i) {
        // FIXME: why is zeta the same each iteration?
        Clustering zeta = clusterGen.makeOneClustering(G);
        DEBUG(&zeta);
        clusterings.push_back(&zeta);
    }
```

The output of the DEBUG statement is

```
0x7fff4ff894d0
0x7fff4ff894d0
0x7fff4ff894d0
```

So this means that `&zeta` is the same pointer in each iteration. Why? 
How can I get the desired result (create one `Clustering` object per iteration and remember it in a vector)?

Comment: first of all `Clustering zeta(n)` is created on the stack - it goes out of scope at that closing brace. if there is no heap allocation (new, etc... not sure how the rest of the code is), it will die

Comment: @AK4749 If I push `zeta` instead of `&zeta` into the vector, will this fix the problem?

Comment: mmm, no. Try Clustering * zeta = new Clustering(n); Then just push zeta

Comment: wait you have a generator class. make that one then return a Clustering *, make the vector hold clustering *s. After that change to new inside the generator

Comment: @AK4749 But why should I modify the original method to include a `new` statement and return a pointer? I'ven been advised in other contexts to generally return by value, not by pointer or reference.

Comment: @AK4749 mmm, yes (istead of no). `Clustering` seems to be copyable pretty well, so really think it over before using dynamic memory allocation here.

Comment: ^ listen to him - if you want to have your memory management done by the STL container (which you should strive for), then actually store Clusterings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `zeta` is an automatic variable (the one in the loop, well the other one is a local variable, too, but there's nothing inherently wrong with `ClusteringGenerator::makeOneClustering`), which doesn't exist anymore once the current loop iteration ends (and `zeta`'s destructor has been called). The compiler is thus free to reuse its underlying storage for further variables (like the `zeta` from the next loop iteration), and would be pretty stupid not to do so.

Likewise is your code error-prone, since it stores the address of a local variable in a container, although this variable doesn't exist anymore after the `push_back`, like described above.

To solve this, well, either just use a `std::vector<Clustering>` and put those things in by value, or, if you really need to store pointers (maybe because you don't use/profit from C++11's move semantics and fear the copying overhead), then allocate those loop objects dynamically, to prevent them from being destroyed automatically. But in the latter case (whose usage you should thoroughly overthink anyway, given that the `Clustering` seems to be copyable pretty well) you should rather use some kind of smart pointer to care for proper destruction of the dynamically allocated objects.

Comment: When I try pushing the `Clustering` objects by value, I get a   
`malloc: error for object 0x10070c5c0: pointer being freed was not allocated`. This happens in the loop and when `~Clustering` is called. I do not understand why a destructor is called there.

Comment: @cls Well, if you copy `zeta` into the vector, its destructor is still called, of course (since you merely copied it), but this sounds more like you have an error otherwhere in your code (maybe in `Clustering`'s destructor, though this should have already shown in your previous version). You're not still using a `std::vector<Clustering*>` and trying to push objects into it, are you (though this should rather result in a compiler error)?

Comment: No, I'm using a `std::vector<Clustering>` now. My code looks like the code in the answer of mgr. `Clustering`s destructor is an empty stub.

Comment: Possibly, the error is elsewhere, so I'll accept the answer for now.

Answer (score 1):

you could define

```
std::vector<Clustering> clusterings;
```

and then use

```
clusterings.push_back(clusterGen.makeOneClustering(G));
```

if you are using c++11 and Clustering is movable you not even generating a copy. This solution is faster and you dont have to deal with raw pointers.

Comment: What do I have to implement to make `Clustering` movable?

Comment: you have to implement a move constructor.

Comment: I tried this and got the error `malloc:  error for object 0x10070c5c0: pointer being freed was not allocated`

Answer (score 0):

Thats because you are printing out the address of the variable you created, and it is always the same. The same thing with the vector. You are storing the address and not the actual value. If you want to store the value, try using this.

```
clustering.push_back(zeta);
```

Now you are storing the value and not the address....

Answer (score -1):

```
Clustering * ClusteringGenerator::makeOneClustering(Graph& G) {
    int64_t n = G.numberOfNodes();
    Clustering * zeta = new Clustering(n);
    cluster one = zeta.addCluster();
    for (node v = G.firstNode(); v <= n; ++v) {
        zeta.addToCluster(one, v);
    }
    return zeta;
}
```

This loop calls the method multiple times and adds the pointer to the return value to a vector.

```
int z = 3
for (int i = 0; i < z; ++i) {
    // FIXME: why is zeta the same each iteration?
    Clustering * zeta = clusterGen.makeOneClustering(G);
    DEBUG(zeta);
    clusterings.push_back(zeta);
}
```

Comment: try that. this is to make minimal code changes. I'm sure some C++ expert here will (correctly) yell at us for not using a standard design pattern such as factory

Comment: This is how my code looked before I followed the advice to return by value: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14198387/626537

Comment: yes, but the problem here is that your code is structured in such a way that your object goes out of scope because you contain and create in two different levels

Comment: if you can refactor to put the object creation and containment in the same level, that would be the preferred way i'd think

Comment: What, a factory? The dynamic memory allocation is most probably wrong in the first place. You don't even mention the much nearer alternative of a `std::vector<Clustering>`.

Comment: @ChristianRau oh no, return by value ("if you can refactor to put the object creation and containment in the same level, [return by value] would be the preferred way i'd think") which would indeed be vector<Clustering>